# Working with memory ouputs in PyQGIS3

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis-3

I have the following code snippet I run in QGIS 3.4 which goes through a list of shapefiles (my_wild) and runs a polygon to lines process. It performs the process and adds them to the map as expected, but how do I do work on them from there?

I want to perform some attribute work and do further processing on the outputs. The print function returns:

output_f8c71c3d_8781_4057_8295_3dd7099f214d

but then the next poly2line_result.startEditing() function returns:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startEditing'

```py
for f in my_wild:
    #get perimeter line for the study area
    poly2line_result = processing.runAndLoadResults(
        'qgis:polygonstolines', 
        {
            'INPUT':f,
            'OUTPUT':'memory:'
        }) ['OUTPUT']
    print(poly2line_result)
    #add attribute field and commit changes
    #poly2line_result.getFeatures()
    poly2line_result.startEditing()
    if poly2line_result.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("Segments") == -1:
            poly2line_result.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Segments",QVariant.Double)])
    poly2line_result.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Result, as expected, is an 'AttributeError' because your 'poly2line_result' is a 'str' object without 'startEditing' method. So, it is preferable that you use 'run' processing method, create a **QgsVectorLayer** with **poly2line_result** string and load it to Map Legend with 'QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer'. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result, as expected, is an **AttributeError** because your **poly2line_result** is a 'str' object without 'startEditing' method. So, it is preferable that you use 'run' processing method, create a **QgsVectorLayer** with **poly2line_result** string and load it to Map Legend with 'QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer'. You can adapt your code from mine (because I only used a vector layer) that it looks as follow:

```
import processing

f = iface.activeLayer()

poly2line_result = processing.run('qgis:polygonstolines', 
                                                {'INPUT':f,
                                                 'OUTPUT':'memory'}) ['OUTPUT']

print(poly2line_result)

layer = QgsVectorLayer(poly2line_result, 'Lines', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

#add attribute field and commit changes
#poly2line_result.getFeatures()
layer.startEditing()
if layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("Segments") == -1:
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Segments",QVariant.Double)])
layer.commitChanges()
```

I ran above code with a polygon layer and I got result of following image; where it can be observed that attributes table of vector line has "Segments" field as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
poly2line_result = processing.run('qgis:polygonstolines', {'INPUT':f,'OUTPUT':'memory'}) ['OUTPUT']
linelayer = poly2line_result['OUTPUT']
newField = QgsField("Segments",QVariant.Double)
linelayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([newField])
linelayer.updateFields()
idx = linelayer.fields().lookupField('Segments')
# in a loop
  attrs = { idx : your_value }
  fid = your_feature.id()
  linelayer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })
```